# Modelling a Database for Recording Taxes

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I need to cater to a complicated system of taxes. Following are the possible scenarios:

1. Simple flat tax rate on net amount e.g. 5%, 12%, 18%, etc.
2. A compound tax (e.g. 5%) which may be composed as below:

   1. State Tax on net amount  - 2.5%
   2. Central Tax on net amount - 2.5%
3. There might also be a case of a compound tax, where taxes are applicable not on net amount, but on the previous `(net amount + tax)`. Eg:

   1. Net Amount = `100`
   2. Row `(1)` Plus `Tax 1` (5%) = `100 + 5` = `105`
   3. Row `(2)` Plus `Tax 2` (5%) on i.e. 5% on 105 = `105 + 5.25` = `110.25`
4. Over and above all this, I need to allow the user to add `user defined` taxes, to cater to those tax situations which my `in-built` taxes don't cover.

**SOME REQUIREMENTS**:

From (4), it is clear there will be some `system-defined` taxes and some `user-defined` taxes.

Another requirement is that in the case of a compound tax, I need to keep track of taxes paid for each component individually. That is, in the examples above, I need to keep track of Central Tax, State Tax, Tax 1 & Tax 2 separately.

I was leaning towards a `self-referencing` `many-to-many` relationship like so:

```
taxes (tax_id, tax_name, tax_rate, ...)
tax_components (tax_id, fk_tax_id, order, ...)
```

The `order` column would be used to describe the computation order, as in case (3) above.

Example tables for case (2) above:

```
taxes
----------------------------------------
| tax_id | tax_name         | tax_rate |
----------------------------------------
| 1      | GST 5%           | 5        |
----------------------------------------
| 2      | State GST 2.5%   | 2.5      |
----------------------------------------
| 3      | Central GST 2.5% | 2.5      |
----------------------------------------

tax_components
------------------------------
| tax_id | fk_tax_id | order |
------------------------------
| 1      | 2         | NA    |
------------------------------
| 1      | 3         | NA    |
------------------------------
```

Problem with this design can be best described in one word - Complicated. It will create a complicated hierarchy of taxes with even more complicated queries.

Can anyone offer a simpler design?

Comment: wtf is this getting close votes. seriously disappointment.

Comment: I would also search for how others design the tax rates in their systems - as to do it solidly is not easy. Take a look how very popular ecommerce platforms are doing it. To get additional point of reference look on open-source code of [WooCommerce Tax Rates](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description#table-woocommerce_tax_rates) to get some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified four types of taxes, but

- one of them is `user defined` unfortunately that probably work. You'll have to define the types of taxes users can *apply*. How will they design the logic for a tax? Unless your providing a logic system, it seems unlikely.
- a compound tax is really just two simple taxes paid to different taxing authorities, so we'll drop the designation of simple and complex and normalize that away.

> Problem with this design can be best described in one word - Complicated. It will create a complicated hierarchy of taxes with even more complicated queries.

The purpose of taxes is quite clear. They're supposed to be complicated. They're puzzles to confuse working class folks so rich capitalists can force their surfs to foot the bill for their own private thugs, armies, and corporate bailouts.

As far as a schema critique. I don't think the self-referencing design makes much sense here, and the constraints are impossible without triggers. I'd ditch it.

```
CREATE SCHEMA tax;

CREATE TYPE tax.cat AS ENUM ('NET', 'GROSS');
CREATE TABLE tax.authority ( authority_id, authority_name, cat, rate, subject )
AS VALUES
  ( 1, 'CA',      'NET',   CAST(0.025 AS real) ),
  ( 2, 'NATIONAL, 'GROSS', CAST(0.025 AS real) );
```

Now you link them together in a linking table. You can easily calculate the `0.050` using `sum()` in a subselect. To change the modes of application just do something like,

```
SELECT
  p.price,
  p.price * t.gross AS gross_tax,
  (p.price - p.cost) * t.net AS net_tax
FROM product AS p
-- should be an inner join if you have a method of going from
-- products to tax authorities
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT
    sum(rate) FILTER (WHERE cat='NET') AS net,
    sum(rate) FILTER (WHERE cat='GROSS') AS gross
  FROM tax
) AS t;
```

Taxes are usually a function of locality, so I would use GIS or allow people to pick their own taxing authorities and what should be collected.

Comment: By `user-defined` taxes, I meant to cover surcharges or cess, that some regions will levy over and above the regular taxes for a region. This usually comes as a tax on tax. e.g. 2% Educational Cess on 5% GST. This would increase ones GST liability by 2% to 5.1% and would need to be tracked as the amount payable to "Education Cess" authority. I want to provide, when defining the "Education Cess" tax an option for specifying it's rate as 2% and what it applies to for eg. GST. From there on, the logic would be generic.

Comment: BTW, love the "They're puzzles to confuse working class folks so rich capitalist...".

Comment: @CodePoet you'd need another category for cess, or what not. All the same schema though. It's just data. The querying method is what gets more complex. Feel free to simplify the query with a function, even a simple SQL one that just produces the result from the input rows.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding how this is taking care of my case (3.3) where a tax is being applied on Net + Tax computation of the previous row?

Comment: @CodePoet provide some sample input sample output, and explain.

Comment: @CodePoet - Presumably, your item 3 represents a case where the tax is not applied to the specified amount (or, with Evan's model, the gross or the net), but to the amount *plus any other taxes being charged*. If this is a real thing, you would presumably need a separate column to indicate this (similar to the net vs gross indicator), and then to add the appropriate calculation. Note that, if there were more than one applicable tax rate for these, it might indeed become necessary to provide some way to correct apply them in order. I'd confirm that this is needed before worrying about it.

Comment: @RDFozz This is a real case, though I doubt there will ever be more than one applicable tax for these. So, perhaps leaving order might simplify things.

Comment: @EvanCarroll There's the case of restaurants levying a service charge over an above the Net+GST (example in case 3 above). So you got you bill Rs.100. You have 5% GST on that. So, net + GST = 105. Now, service charge (say 10%) is legally supposed to be levied on 105, not 100 (the net) and it's supposed to come last in the calculation order.

Answer (score 0):

given the complexity of your requirements and the need for a flexible, yet simple, database schema to handle various tax scenarios, I propose a slightly different approach that maintains flexibility while potentially reducing complexity. This approach involves creating a more straightforward relationship between taxes and their components without requiring a self-referencing many-to-many relationship. Here’s a revised design:

#### Tables:

1. **taxes**

   - `tax_id` (PK)
   - `tax_name`
   - `is_compound` (boolean to indicate if the tax is compound or not)
   - `applies_on_net_amount` (boolean, true if the tax applies on net amount, false if it applies on amount + previous taxes)
2. **tax_components**

   - `component_id` (PK)
   - `tax_id` (FK to `taxes.tax_id`)
   - `component_name`
   - `component_rate`
   - `order` (to indicate computation order in case of compound taxes)
3. **user_defined_taxes** (optional, depending on the requirement for user flexibility)

   - `user_tax_id` (PK)
   - `user_defined_name`
   - `details` (Could be a JSON field to store various attributes of user-defined taxes)

#### Simplifications and Advantages:

- **Direct Relationship**: Each tax can directly relate to its components without the need for a tax to reference another tax, simplifying queries.
- **Flexibility**: This design still allows for both system-defined and user-defined taxes, and can easily accommodate compound taxes and their computation order.
- **Compound and Non-Compound Distinction**: The `is_compound` flag in the `taxes` table helps in quickly identifying if a tax is compound, and the `applies_on_net_amount` flag helps to determine the base for tax calculation.
- **Easy Tracking of Components**: Each component of a tax is a separate record in `tax_components`, making it easy to track and report taxes paid for each component individually.

#### Example:

For the compound tax scenario mentioned (5% GST composed of 2.5% State Tax and 2.5% Central Tax), the entries would be:

**taxes**

```
| tax_id | tax_name | is_compound | applies_on_net_amount |
|--------|----------|-------------|-----------------------|
| 1      | GST 5%   | true        | true                  |
```

**tax_components**

```
| component_id | tax_id | component_name | component_rate | order |
|--------------|--------|----------------|----------------|-------|
| 1            | 1      | State GST 2.5% | 2.5            | 1     |
| 2            | 1      | Central GST 2.5%| 2.5           | 2     |
```

#### Considerations:

- **Scalability and Performance**: While this design is simpler and more direct, performance and scalability considerations should be taken into account, especially with the potential for a large number of records